# Display output for each input in mysql query + linux

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I have a query something like this:

```
select * from bulk_upload_subscribers where SUBSCRIBER_ID='123456';
```

Output of this query yields me:

```
TASK_ID | PROCESS_TIME 
4790 | 2015-03-26 14:19:15
5784 | 2015-09-10 12:29:50
6001 | 2015-10-12 19:37:34
6020 | 2015-10-14 16:52:36
```

Now, I just require the last/latest output as per date. ie. desired output:

```
6020 | 2015-10-14 16:52:36
```

To achieve this, I am using below query and which actually works too!

```
select * from bulk_upload_subscribers where SUBSCRIBER_ID='123456' ORDER BY PROCESS_TIME desc limit 1;
```

Now, the main scenario is that, I am writing a Join query to fetch the 'task_id' and based upon the task_id I am fetching 'task_name' from different table. The query is:

```
select a.SUBSCRIBER_ID,b.TASK_ID,b.task_name AS Campaign_name from bulk_upload_subscribers a,bulk_upload_tasks b where subscriber_id in ('123456','234567','345678') and a.task_id=b.task_id order by a.PROCESS_TIME desc limit 1;
```

Above query yields me only one value because of `limit 1`. Could anyone guide me how can i achieve the task? Output must have 3 task names for each of SUBSCRIBER_ID.

```
NOTE: I have around 600 SUBSCRIBER_ID's. Solution via scripting will also help me.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your program exactly for this issue, I guess you can use loop to print for each SUBSCRIBER_ID.

For eg., You can create a procedure for loop like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 10 THEN
      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
  SET @x = p1;
END;
```

This will help you to print the output for each of the SUBSCRIBER_ID.